# SQL: rename only part of the columns in a joined table

Tags: sql, select, join

I have the following SQL query:

```
with table_new as (
  select a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id from table_a a 
  left outer join table_b b 
   on a.col_x = b.id
  )

select * from table_new where b_id is null
```

The code above works fine. However, I want the `table_new` to display all columns of the joined table instead of just `a_id` and `b_id`. However, the joined table has too many columns, it is impossible to type every column one by one without using `select *`

So I am wondering how do I display all columns in the joined table, but only rename two of the columns (`a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id`) ? That is, I am looking for something like :

pseudo code:

```
select *, a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id from table_a a 
  left outer join table_b b 
   on a.col_x = b.id
```

Is this possible?

Comment: the only way you can do this (i think) is to create a temp table with all the fields from A and B with A_ID and B_ID and do insert into to the temp table

Comment: provided that all fields in A and B are going to be displayed?

Comment: The code you provided as pseudo code should work fine. The fact that you have values of 2 id's displayed twice in 2 different columns should not cause any issue. I would still suggest to explicitly specify all the columns you need to select.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Well, my pseudo code doesn't work, and this is the error: SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver] ... So I case it is a HDFS database?